# Get datetime object representing most recent occurrence of a specific time in Python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want a datetime object representing the most recent occurrence of a given time. Is there a built in datetime method for accomplishing this or will I have to do something like

```
from datetime import datetime, time

now = datetime.now()
if now.time() < time(6, 30):
```

to find the most recent occurence of the time 6:30am

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by specifying a `checkHour` and `checkMinute` and checking it against the current `datetime`.

If it is greater, then we can construct a `datetime` object for today at `checkHour` and `checkMinute`

If it is not greater, we can construct the same `datetime` object for yesterday.

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

now = datetime.now()

## Set our hour and minutes to check against ##
checkHour = 6
checkMinute = 30

## Construct a datetime object for our checkHour and checkMinute today ##
checkTime = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, checkHour, checkMinute)

## If the current time is greater then our checkTime ##
if now > checkTime:

    ## Construct datetime object for checkHour, checkMinute today ##

    most_recent = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, checkHour, checkMinute)
else:

    ## Else return the date of yesterday ##

    yesterday = now - timedelta(days=1)
    most_recent = datetime(yesterday.year, yesterday.month, yesterday.day, checkHour, checkMinute)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will determine the most recent occurrence of an event (i.e., the last time a given `target_time` happened before `ref_datetime`.

```python
import datetime

def get_most_recent_occurrence_of_daily_event(ref_datetime: datetime.datetime, target_time: datetime.time) -> datetime.datetime:
    """
    Gets the most recent time, before `ref_datetime`, that `target_time` happened. 
    Can be used to get the most recent time a daily event occured (like the most recent time a daily email was sent).

    Partial Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149244
    """

    check_time = datetime(ref_datetime.year, ref_datetime.month, ref_datetime.day, target_time.hour, target_time.minute, target_time.second)

    if ref_datetime > check_time:
        return check_time
    else:
        return check_time - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Example usage to find the most recent time 8AM happened:

```
get_most_recent_occurrence_of_daily_event(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.time(8, 0, 0))
```